# Can we communicate with Xbee from host programatically

Tags: python, arduino, xbee

I am trying to hook up a xbee on arduino and wish to run some algorithms on my linux machine and based on result of algorithmic output i ahve to communicate the commands to xbee connected to my arduino. I know we have API support to read/write xbee from Arduino platform. Does Xbee have a way to be programmed on host machine running Linux/OSx other than x-ctu software.
I wish to know if there is a way to programmatically communicate Xbee using USB dongle adapter from host machine, may be python api

Answer (score 1):

I found this online http://serdmanczyk.github.io/XBeeAPI-PythonArduino-Tutorial/ and it pretty much addresses my need .